# Firebase error 17007

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17007 "The email address is
already in use by another account." UserInfo= {NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is already in use by another account., error_name=ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoEmailKey=my@gmail.com}
```

Проблема в том, что почта уже используется для входа через google, а при входе через facebook выходит эта ошибка и юсер не создается. Как решить эту проблему, чтобы юсер заходил через одну почту, но через две соц сети

Comment: а вопрос в чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете разрешить создавать несколько аккаунтов для одного адреса электронной почты.

В консоли Firebase перейдите на вкладку "Autentification", нажмите ИЗМЕНИТЬ справа внизу и выберите РАЗРЕШИТЬ

[image: схема]